# Start android application without activity

Tags: android, android-manifest, startup

I've an application which aims to run only as a service (no interface, just run in background). I have no activity mentioned in my AndroidManifest.xml but put a receiver to start the application at phone start.

```
<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
    <service
        android:enabled="true"
        android:name=".MyAppService">
        <intent-filter>
            <action
                android:name = "me.myapp.MyAppService">
            </action>
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
    <receiver
        android:enabled="true"
        android:name=".BootReceiver">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name = "android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
</application>
```

The problem is that as I'm developing (using Eclipse) the application, I need to test my changes often. When I run the application (with my phone connected in debug mode), I've got a message like

```
[2011-12-14 00:18:40 - MyApp] Android Launch!
[2011-12-14 00:18:40 - MyApp] adb is running normally.
[2011-12-14 00:18:40 - MyApp] No Launcher activity found!
[2011-12-14 00:18:40 - MyApp] The launch will only sync the application package on the device!
[2011-12-14 00:18:40 - MyApp] Performing sync
```

How can I start the application at run, without having to restart it every time ?

---

**Edit** this is not possible anymore for Android 3.1 or above. [Source](http://commonsware.com/blog/2011/07/13/boot-completed-regression-confirmed.html)

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Apart from the two options mentioned by EboMike: You can always send the `BOOT_COMPLETED` broadcast via the command line instead of rebooting your phone.

Use

```
adb shell am broadcast -a android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED
```

This will result in a situation like after an actual reboot, and will also trigger any 3rd party apps boot receivers. After typing it once in a terminal you can usually repeat it simply by pressing the up-arrow key followed by return on most operating systems. Or you can include it in a script thats triggered after reinstalling your app.

---

If you want to limit the broadcast to your app only, you can also specify a component:

```
adb shell am broadcast -a android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED -n your.app.packagename/.YourReceiverClassName
```

This sends the reboot broadcast only to your receiver. All other apps are not called.

Comment: Thanks, nice way to go. Maybe I can also create my own event that only my application can catch to avoid conflict with other 3rd party apps.

Comment: @MartinTrigaux Just checked the docs and remembered that it's possible to specify a component to achieve that. See my edit.

Answer (score 2):

Option 1: Add a dummy activity that will start your service. Remove it before shipping.

Option 2: Create a second test application that starts your service.

Comment: How will the app behave at runtime? What will make the application run? Running after boot isn't good enough, as Android may kill the process. What will initiate it again?

Answer (score 1):

Starting The service using Broadcast receiver through any Intent like

`android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED`

is **not possible above Android 3.1 until the user uses your app**, 
and thus to use your app there must be a single non UI activity (which can call finish in oncreate()).

[See the proof here](http://commonsware.com/blog/2011/07/13/boot-completed-regression-confirmed.html)