# android application to appear only on apps list in settings

Tags: android

I have a silly question. Just wanted to know if it is possible.

I have to install an application and it should not show up in the applications launcher screen and it should show up only in the settings/apps list. Is this possible ?

One of my friends had asked me this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want this you have to remove the `CATEGORY` `LAUNCHER` from any of your app activities(from the `intent-filter`) in the `AndroidManifest.xml` file.

This is the line to remove:

```
<category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
```

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, you can achieve this by doing the following:

Delete this block from your manifest:

```
 <intent-filter >
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
 </intent-filter>
```

By doing this, your app won't show up in the launcher screen. You can start an app otherwise by following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8497885/start-android-application-without-activity%22this%22) link which might help you do the same. I doubt if it can show up only in the settings/apps list though.