# What´s create only project service Android

Tags: android

I want to create a monitoring application
Activity that has not UI and only be a service which is started when boot Android.
I create a project that contains no activity.
The idea is that the service send information to a server.
Receiving information service of Google GCM.

Comment: take a look --> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8497885/start-android-application-without-activity

Comment: Thanks, I try it and I told them.
If there are other suggestions made ​​the comment.