# How should Install this app?

Tags: android, service, live-wallpaper

I have this application i want to install it (it is service) but i don't have an activity so i can't install it on my device to try it can someone help me please i guess this is livewallpaper for photo sequence like slideshow so can anyone tell me what should i do?

```
public class MainActivity extends WallpaperService{

 Handler handler;
private boolean visible;

public void onCreate()
{
    super.onCreate();
}

public void onDestroy()
{
    super.onDestroy();
}

public Engine onCreateEngine()
{
    return new CercleEngine();
}

class CercleEngine extends Engine
{
    public Bitmap image1, image2, image3;

    CercleEngine()
    {
        image1 = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.greenww);
        image2 = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.redww);
        image3 = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.screen3);
    }

    public void onCreate(SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder)
    {
        super.onCreate(surfaceHolder);
    }

    public void onOffsetsChanged(float xOffset, float yOffset, float xStep, float yStep, int xPixels, int yPixels)
    {
        drawFrame();
    }





    void drawFrame()
    {
        final SurfaceHolder holder = getSurfaceHolder();

        Canvas c = null;
        try
        {
            c = holder.lockCanvas();
            if (c != null)
            {
                c.drawBitmap(image1, 0, 0, null);
                c.drawBitmap(image2, 0, 0, null);
                c.drawBitmap(image3, 0, 0, null);
            }
        } finally
        {
            if (c != null) holder.unlockCanvasAndPost(c);
        }
        handler.removeCallbacks(drawRunner);
        if (visible)
        {
            handler.postDelayed(drawRunner, 1000); // delay 1 sec
        }
    }
    private final Runnable drawRunner = new Runnable()
    {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            drawFrame();
        }

    };

}
```

manifest

```
  <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.mike.wallpaper2">
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SET_WALLPAPER" />





       <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SET_WALLPAPER" />





<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">


    <service
        android:enabled="true"
        android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action
                android:name = "me.myapp.MyAppService">
            </action>
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
    <receiver android:enabled="true"
        android:name=".BootUpReceiver">
        <intent-filter> <action
            android:name = "android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
</application>
```

BootUpReceiver

```
public class BootUpReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    /***** For start Service  ****/
    Intent myIntent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
    context.startService(myIntent);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From EditConfiguration **LUNCH OPTION (NOTHING)**

Answer (score 0):

add/update this code in manifest

```
<service
    android:enabled="true"
    android:name=".MainActivity">
    <intent-filter>
        <action
            android:name = "com.example.mike.wallpaper2.MainActivity">
        </action>
    </intent-filter>
</service>
<receiver
    android:enabled="true"
    android:name=".BootReceiver">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name = "android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

also add one new class

```
public class BootReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
 @Override
 public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
   Intent service = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
   context.startService(service);
 }
}
```

then follow steps mentioned in following example [Start android application without activity](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8498069/3522570)

or restart your device this service start running

Comment: i have this class too 
 public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        /***** For start Service  ****/
        Intent myIntent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
        context.startService(myIntent);
    }
}

Comment: BootUpReceiver.

Comment: <receiver
    android:enabled="true"
    android:name=".BootReceiver">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name = "android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>

Comment: sorry one more correction in manifest     android:name = "com.example.mike.wallpaper2.MainActivity">

Comment: add this and restart device

Comment: I have red X on the select run/debug config.

Comment: in the service or in the receiver ?? and still the same :(

Comment: still can run it btw i dont have layout xml maybe that's the problem ??

Comment: not at all ... did you add everything? then restart device

Comment: add logs in OnCreate and in OnDestroy ... that way you can check your service start running after restart...

Comment: Could not identify launch activity: Default Activity not found
Error while Launching activity

Comment: provide complete log after restart in Question

Comment: it not lunching to write a logcat

Comment: then how can you say this "Could not identify launch activity: Default Activity not found Error while Launching activity –"

Comment: the apk not installing in the device so there is no on create or ondestroy working even can't see the log that i created

Comment: Buddy don't feel bad but you need to study more basic things about Android before this... you have one service this has two methods onCreate and onDestroy

Comment: upload project on Github and share link

Comment: sry i don't know how

Comment: all i wanted a live wallpaper with my own drawable picture appears every 1 hour or day i puted like 50 question and google it i can't find what i want

Comment: Lol... then you can do same:)